# Identifying French character in Winedt

Tags: unicode

I've encountered a problem with my LaTeX file, I asked to change my work from English to French language so this is what I've changed:

```
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
```

to

```
\usepackage[UTF-8]{inputenc}
```

This took me to another problem I cannot identify.

These are the packages I loaded:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}<br>
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amsfonts,amssymb,amscd}<br>
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}<br>
\usepackage[UTF-8]{inputenc}
\pagestyle{plain}%{\markboth{\normalsize \it OpÃÂ©rateurs de
%Hankel}{\normalsize \sl UnicitÃÂ© et StabilitÃÂ© du problÃÂ©me inverse}}
\oddsidemargin0cm \evensidemargin0cm<br>
\usepackage{graphicx}<br>
\usepackage{graphics}<br>
\usepackage{amsfonts}<br>
\usepackage{indentfirst}<br>
\usepackage[frenchb,english]{babel}<br>
\textheight22cm \textwidth16cm<br>
%@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@<br>
\def\chaptername{chapitre}<br>
\pagestyle{plain}<br>
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}<br>
\newtheorem{acknowledgement}[theorem]{Acknowledgement}<br>
\newtheorem{algorithm}[theorem]{Algorithm}<br>
\newtheorem{axiom}[theorem]{Axiom}<br>
\newtheorem{thm}{Th\'{e}or\`{e}me}[section]<br>
\newtheorem{cor}[thm]{Corollaire}<br>
\newtheorem{exer}[thm]{exercice}<br>
\newtheorem{lem}[thm]{Lemme}<br>
\newtheorem{lemma}[thm]{Lemma}<br>
\newtheorem{pro}[thm]{Proposition}<br>
\newtheorem{prop}[thm]{Propri\'{e}t\'{e}}<br>
\newtheorem{proprs}[thm]{Propri\'{e}t\'{e}s}<br>
\newtheorem{d\'{e}fn}[thm]{D\'{e}finition}<br>
\newtheorem{them}[thm]{Th\'{e}or\`{e}me}<br>
\newtheorem{rem}[thm]{Remarque}<br>
\newtheorem{rems&d\'{e}fn}[thm]{Remarque et d\'{e}finition}<br>
\newtheorem{dem}[thm]{D\'{e}monstration}<br>
\newtheorem{exmp}[thm]{Exemple}<br>
\newtheorem{exmps}[thm]{Exemples}<br>
\newtheorem{nota}[thm]{Notation}<br>
\newtheorem{rems}[thm]{Remarques}<br>
\newtheorem{goal}[thm]{Goal}<br>
\newtheorem{notas}[thm]{Notations}<br>
\newtheorem{hyp}[thm]{HypothÃÂ¨se}<br>
\newtheorem{defprop}[thm]{D\'{e}finition-Proposition}<br>
\newcommand{\set}[1]{\left\{#1\right\}}<br>
\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}<br>
\newcommand{\N}{\mathds{N}}<br>
\newcommand{\F}{\mathcal{F}}<br>
\newcommand{\A}{{\cal A}}<br>
\newcommand{\E}{\mathcal{E}}<br>
\newcommand{\h}{{\cal H}}<br>
\newcommand{\s}{{\cal S}}<br>
\newcommand{\C}{\mathcal{C}}<br>
\newcommand{\G}{\mathcal{G}}<br>
\newcommand{\Fn}{\mathcal{F}_n}<br>
\newcommand{\Field}{\mathbf{F}}<br>
\newcommand{\RPlus}{\R^{+}}<br>
\newcommand{\To}{\longrightarrow}<br>
\newcommand{\norm}[1]{\left\Vert#1\right\Vert}<br>
\newcommand{\essnorm}[1]{\norm{#1}_{\text{\rm\normalshape ess}}}<br>
\vsize 29.7cm \hsize 19cm \topmargin 0.23cm \textheight 22cm<br>
\textwidth 15cm \oddsidemargin 0.5cm \evensidemargin 0.5cm<br>
\newcommand{\biindice}[3]%.<br>
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%<br>
{ #1\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.5}\begin{array}[t]{c}<br>
{\scriptstyle #2}\\<br>
{\scriptstyle #3}\end{array}<br>
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1}}<br>
\def\contentsname{Table des matiÃÂ©res}<br>
\def \endproof {\quad \hfill  \rule{2mm}{2mm}\par\medskip}<br>
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%<br>
%Included for Gather Purpose only:<br>
%input "Xbib.bib"<br>
%\bibliographystyle{amsplain}<br>
%\bibliography{xbib}<br>
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
```

And this is what the console gives me as an error:

```
Command Line:   bibtex.exe "introduction lotka"
Startup Folder: C:\Users\MANEL\Documents

This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (MiKTeX 2.9)
The top-level auxiliary file: introduction lotka.aux
I found no \citation commands---while reading file introduction lotka.aux
I found no \bibdata command---while reading file introduction lotka.aux
I found no \bibstyle command---while reading file introduction lotka.aux
(There were 3 error messages)


Command Line:   texify.exe --pdf --tex-option=--interaction=errorstopmode --tex-option=--synctex=-1 "C:\Users\MANEL\Documents\introduction lotka.tex"
Startup Folder: C:\Users\MANEL\Documents

This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.3-1.40.12 (MiKTeX 2.9)
entering extended mode
("C:/Users/MANEL/Documents/introduction lotka.tex"
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
Babel <v3.8m> and hyphenation patterns for english, afrikaans, ancientgreek, ar
abic, armenian, assamese, basque, bengali, bokmal, bulgarian, catalan, coptic, 
croatian, czech, danish, dutch, esperanto, estonian, farsi, finnish, french, ga
lician, german, german-x-2009-06-19, greek, gujarati, hindi, hungarian, iceland
ic, indonesian, interlingua, irish, italian, kannada, kurmanji, lao, latin, lat
vian, lithuanian, malayalam, marathi, mongolian, mongolianlmc, monogreek, ngerm
an, ngerman-x-2009-06-19, nynorsk, oriya, panjabi, pinyin, polish, portuguese, 
romanian, russian, sanskrit, serbian, slovak, slovenian, spanish, swedish, swis
sgerman, tamil, telugu, turkish, turkmen, ukenglish, ukrainian, uppersorbian, u
senglishmax, welsh, loaded.
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\report.cls"
Document Class: report 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\size12.clo"))
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\ams\math\amsmath.sty"
For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\ams\math\amstext.sty"
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\ams\math\amsgen.sty"))
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\ams\math\amsbsy.sty")
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\ams\math\amsopn.sty"))
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\ams\classes\amsthm.sty")
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\amsfonts\amsfonts.sty")
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\amsfonts\amssymb.sty")
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\ams\math\amscd.sty")
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\fontenc.sty"
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\t1enc.def"))
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\inputenc.sty"

! LaTeX Error: File `UTF-8.def' not found.

Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: def)

Enter file name:
```

So is there any solution to fix it?

Comment: Please make your code a MWE (minimal and working).

Comment: Changing from latin1 to utf8 is wrong unless you also reencode your file.

Comment: Could you please explain more

Comment: With a current winedt you can use `file -> Convert to UTF-8`. Winedt will ask you to choose a code page. Take `1252  ANSI Windows Latin 1 (Western European)`. Make a backup first in case you are doing something wrong. The conversion is not needed to write french, but on the whole using utf8 is recommended anyway.

Comment: Sir, i'm using winedt 9.1 and i cannot find the "file->convert to UTF-8" option that you mentioned to me !

Comment: Either update, or create a new file encoded as UTF8 and copy and paste the content of your file in it (winedt 9.1. has some conversion menu too but imho it was confusing). And I'm not a "Sir".

Comment: The `pÃÂ©r` you show above suggests that your file is UTF-8 so you should use `[utf8]` however if your file is latin1 then just keep using `[latin1]` . latin1 includes all characters needed for French. The error you show is simply the option name is wrong, it is `utf8` not `UTF-8`.

Comment: It doesn't work with me eather i create a new file encoded with utf8 or UTF-8 or leave like it is latin1 and just change the file encoding setting and this is how it looks like: http://hpics.li/2f2af0c and http://hpics.li/d0697d4

Comment: I don't know the editor but I assume the green utf8 at the bottom means the file is in utf-8 currently and the menu you show is offering to save it as "ansi" (weird microsoft name for a variant of latin1)  so either save the file in utf8 and use the `[utf8]` option or save it in ansi (or latin1 or iso-8859-1 if there is that option) and use `[latin1]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Goto to `WinEdt.org`, more precisely to the [Macros](http://www.winedt.org/macros.html) page, download the `ANSI2UTF8` macro and install it. You'll have a `Convert to UTF8…` submenu in the `File` menu.

[image]

Comment: Oh I think you are right. I forgot that it is in some external package.

Comment: I did what exactely you told me and i installed the macro and use the convert to UTF-8 menu and i choosed 1252 ANSI Windows Latin 1 (Western European) and if i use \usepackage[UTF-8]{inputenc} the console gives me the error code above and when i use \usepackage[latin1]{inputenc} or \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} it gives me the error in that link  http://txt.do/drrua :( P.S i wan't to thank you for all your effor to help me

Comment: Maybe you now have a mix of UTF8 and Latin1 in your file? Try getting back to an older version (when the encoding was `latin1`). To get it, go to  the `C:\Users\Your_User_Name\AppData\Roaming\WinEdt Team\_history` directory and ask to search for your file, filling the  `Rechercher dans` form with your file name, or a significant part of its name. Convert one of these to UTF8.

Comment: @HamzaHsn the link you give  http://textuploader.com/drrua shows that you have specified latin1 but the file is in utf8 so use `[utf8]`. It also shows that you have not updated miktex for a very long time, your latex format is 6 years old.

Comment: I would add the editor should also be updated (we're at version 10.2!).

Comment: unfortunately i've tried so many times with many options and it didn't work with me :(

Comment: @HamzaHsn it will work but you keep changing what you say is the input, and do not give a clear indication of the error. i would start a new file with a different name and make sure the editor saves it in utf8 and then copy in the text of the old file and make sure that it says `[uf8]` if that fails, fix your question to have a _complete_ small document that people can test and also show the full error that you get from tex.

Comment: Thank every one for their effort to help me, and now it's works for me, so i uninstalled the winedt 9.1 version that i got and i reinstall the 10.1 version and i installed the macro that @Bernard sayed so it worked fine so thank you again

Comment: Not the `10.2` version? (Note there'll be a new build  this month).